# Equal Variables Not Returning as Equal

Tags: javascript, variables

Despite the two groups (userTry and username & passTry and pass) being equal, the code returns nothing occurring in the login function that handles the case when those two are equal. Instead of what should be an introduction to the user, the page returns nothing and I am curious as to why there is no indication of those two variables being equal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Create an Account:</p>

<button onclick="create()">Sign Up</button>
<button onclick="login()">Login</button>
<button onclick="doc()">Make a Document</button>

<p id="username"></p>
<p id="pass"></p>
<p id="login"></p>
<p id="welcome"></p>
<p id="name"></p>
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="text"></p>

<script>

function create() {

    var name = prompt("Enter Your Name:", "Name");
    var username = prompt("Please enter a Username:", "username");
    var pass = prompt("Please enter a Password:", "password");

    if (username != null) {
      if (pass != null) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
        "You have signed up successfully!";
      }
    }
}

function login() {

  var userTry=prompt("Enter Your Username", "Username");
  var passTry=prompt("Enter Your Password", "Password");

  if (userTry==username && passTry==pass) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
    "Welcome! Current User: " + name;
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Debug what's happening and it will make sense why. Your variable scopes are not what you are assuming they are.

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of the `login` function the variables `username` and `pass` are not declared. This should give you a ReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've defined the variables `username` and `pass` in the function `create()`, their scope ends after the function ends. So to use them globally you need to declare them globally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Create an Account:</p>

<button onclick="create()">Sign Up</button>
<button onclick="login()">Login</button>
<button onclick="doc()">Make a Document</button>

<p id="username"></p>
<p id="pass"></p>
<p id="login"></p>
<p id="welcome"></p>
<p id="name"></p>
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="text"></p>

<script>

var name;
var username;
var pass;

function create() {
    name = prompt("Enter Your Name:", "Name");
    username = prompt("Please enter a Username:", "username");
    pass = prompt("Please enter a Password:", "password");

    if (username != null) {
      if (pass != null) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
        "You have signed up successfully!";
      }
    }
}

function login() {

  var userTry=prompt("Enter Your Username", "Username");
  var passTry=prompt("Enter Your Password", "Password");

  if (userTry==username && passTry==pass) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
    "Welcome! Current User: " + name;
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, the variables are out of scope so you're probably getting an unseen JS error.  It's generally a good idea to use developer tool when messing with JS/Jquery.  Both Chrome and Firefox have Developer tools already built in:

If you're using Chrome:
Options > More Tools > Developer Tools

If you're using Firefox:
Options > Web Developer > Developer Toolbar

If you open those up and then go to your page, you should see the error in the console window.  Also, when making JS changes you may need to periodically delete your cache to get rid of the older JS version.